# How to save a text file as an array of strings in MIPS

Tags: string, assembly, mips, mars-simulator, null-terminated

I am creating a program to read a list of strings from a text file, and store them in an array (in memory, but formatted like an array of strings). I am on Windows running MIPS on MARS. The text file is formatted so that each word is on a new line. I can successfully open and read the file into an input buffer. However, this is where the problem arises. There are no null terminating characters separating the strings, so when I go to print an individual string it prints that string and every string that follows.

```
.data
dictionary:     .asciiz "dictionary.txt"
inputBuffer:        .space  14976   # 2496 * 6 bytes needed, 4 letter words + null character, 1 byte = 1 char

.text
openDictionary:
la $a0, dictionary  # load address of file
addi $a1, $zero, 0
addi $a2, $zero, 0
li $v0, 13      # syscall to open file 
syscall 
    
move $t0, $v0       #t0 now holds file descriptor

# read from file 
li $v0, 14      # load read file service 
move $a0, $t0       # load file descriptor a0
la $a1, inputBuffer # set a1 to address of inputBuffer
addi $a2, $zero, 14946  # set a2 to max number of chars to read, 2496 different words * 4 bytes ( 4 letter words )
syscall 

li, $v0, 4
la $a0, inputBuffer
syscall




jr $ra
```

The output is a list of words but should only be one word.

```
abed
abet
able
ably
abut
acai
aced
aces
ache
achy
acid
acme
acne
acre
acts
adds
adit
adze
aeon
afar
afro
agar
aged
ages
agog
ague
ahem
aide
aids
ails
aims
airs
```

Comment: This is not really an assembly problem.  The data is coming from the file but is not in a format that you want.  You'd have this problem in C as well.  Better and easier to solve in C, then take solution to assembly.  If you need nulls then put them whereever you want.  Or if you know each word is only 4 characters long then just print those 4 characters, or, copy them somewhere that has a null after and print that.  Either way you do it, it is not an assembly or MARS issue, it is of data structures and data formats, so figure out what you want and what you have, then code to convert.

Comment: Also, use the simulator's debugger to inspect your `inputBuffer`.  Inspect at least the 10 characters and observe how the words appear in memory and how two words are separated.

Comment: @ErikEidt I have already solved the problem in C, I separated the words by searching for an "\n", newline, and saving each word into an array of strings. I will use the debugger and try my luck there thank you. Is there a way to only print 4 characters? The syscall for print strings seems to only look for a NUL character.

Comment: Yes, there is a syscall to print one character; would be like `printf("%c", ch);` in C, or, like `putchar(ch);`